# Release memory by using correct method in JNI to prevent memory leak

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have some questions for below codes ! Do I need to release mConnectEnv, s_jObj, jmethodConnect ? Following my infos that I searched in google. I don't need to release jmethodConnect, how about mConnectEnv and s_jObj ? Therefore when I release j_ip, I used deleteLocalRef, I think this way is wrong! Should I use the ReleaseStringUTF method ?

```
static JNIEnv* mConnectEnv = 0;
static jobject s_jObj;
static jmethodID jmethodConnect;
.............(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
   mConnectEnv = env;
   jclass s_jclass = (jclass)(*mConnectEnv)->GetObjectClass(mConnectEnv, obj);
   s_jObj = (*mConnectEnv)->NewGlobalRef(mConnectEnv, obj);

   jmethodConnect = (*mConnectEnv)->GetMethodID(mConnectEnv, s_jclass , "Connect", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z");
..............
}
int OpenConnection(char* ip, int port)
{
    LOG_INFO("OpenConnectionat jni layer");
    jstring j_ip = (*mConnectEnv)->NewStringUTF(mConnectEnv, ip);
    int result = (*mConnectEnv)->CallBooleanMethod(mConnectEnv, s_jObj, jmethodConnect, j_ip, port);
    (*mConnectEnv)->DeleteLocalRef(mConnectEnv, j_ip);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to release mConnectEnv, s_jObj, jmethodConnect ?

```
static JNIEnv* mConnectEnv = 0;
static jobject s_jObj;
static jmethodID jmethodConnect;
```

- `mConnectEnv`: No but this is a misfeature in your code. JNIEnv * is provided by JNI, not by you. TYou should not be storing this in a static variable at all, you should use the one provided in the JNI call, or else call `AttachCurrentThread()` to get a new one.
- `s_jObj`: Yes. You need to free it some time with `DeleteGlobalRef()`.
- `jMethodConnect`: no. MethodIDs are not objects and do not need to be released.

> Therefore when I release j_ip, I used deleteLocalRef, I think this way is wrong! Should I use the ReleaseStringUTF method ?

You don't need to to anything. All `jobjects` that you acquire during a JNI method call are released automatically when the method returns.

Comment: If I use AttachCurrentThread, should I use like the below code ? =>
    `JNIEnv* jenv = 0:
java_jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&jenv,NULL);`
I will init java_jvm somewhere before the above code `jenv->GetJavaVM(&java_jvm);` 
What do you think about it ?

Comment: I think you're going round in circles. You can't use the JNIEnv to get the JavaVM when you are only getting the JavaVM so you can get the JNIEnv. It's not clear to me that you need to call AttachThread at all. Most probably you should just be passing the JNIEnv around as a apart are where needed.

Comment: @HienNguyen `DeleteLocalRef` is always optional but should be used if objects are created in a loop or inside helper functions like `OpenConnection`. And, it is the correct method to release an object created by `NewStringUTF`. `ReleaseStringUTFChars` is used only to clean up after `GetStringUTFChars`.

Comment: @EJP :( In my case, I want to call from C to java, I don't know how to do that because I haven't known how to get JNIEnv in C. Like my example, OpenConnection will call to java from C